# Stop timer of first form

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have two forms. When I clicked on a button of first form then second form is open. After 30 second second form automatically open. If I click on button, second form open but timers are in running state. I want to stop that when second form open. How I do that?

```
 timer= new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
 timer.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrWmpPlayerPosition2_Tick);
 timer.Enabled = true;
 timer.Interval = 30000;
 timer.Start();
```

Comment: how does this deal with asp.net?

Comment: Just use `timer.Stop();` in your button click event (I am assuming WinForms by the way, your question makes no sense in ASP.Net context)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this - the accent in text is too thick. Is this `winforms`?

Comment: @DrewKennedy. He has Form1. He can click a button that opens form2, else form2 opens by itself after 30 seconds. His issue: He clicks the button to open the form, but after 30 seconds the form2 opens again. He wants to stop the timer when the form2 opens or really even if the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your `button_click event`, just call `Timer.Stop()` before you open your second form. If the form2 opens naturally by itself, then you shouldn't even have to worry about the timer...however if you do...

Right before you open the form do this:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.updateEvent += new EventHandler(handleUpdateEvent);

/.........
void handleUpdateEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.stop();
}
```